# Appending ?k=* to URL auto redirects to osssearchresults page unexpectedly

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

We encountered an unexpected behavior yesterday on a clients tenant where if we appended ?k= and any search query after that it would redirect to /_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx page when it shouldn't.

We are currently investigating what has changed on the tenant, since this behavior cannot be reproduced on other tenants.

We tried comparing Search settings, but no difference.

Is there a setting or something else we are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By comparing network requests it was identified that the client had added and loaded a custom script on the impacted tenant, which was to blame for the re-direct.